# Google Play Store App v5.7.10 Bug Cropping Feature Graphics

Tags: android, user-interface, google-play, google-apps

Latest Android Google Play Store App version **(v5.7.10)** has a minor UI bug that affects the App's Feature Graphics in Lollipop [5.0+] devices, the new version seems to be cropping the (1024 x 500) image which results in displaying the symmetrical images wrongly.

Here's a screenshot of two apps that shows the bug in feature graphics in New play store version comparing to the old one.

[image]

[image]

**I am a UI and Graphic designer, How I can report this bug to google, it will be hard to redesign all my client's feature graphics.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to hear you're having issues! To report problems related to Google Play Store, you can contact Google either using the official Google Play forum (*English*): https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/play or via email (*English, Korean, Chinese, and Japanese*): https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/otherbugs. They'll reply within 2 business days.

Comment: Thank you for the links, I reported the problem to google and will be fixed in the next app release.